# I get "IndexError: list index out of range" when installing Pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

So, I installed pandas with cmd :

[image: CMD Screenshot]

but when I try to import it i get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Uros/Desktop/fasda.py", line 1, in 
>       import pandas  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

and when I try to install it in setting I get this error:
[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Please post console output as code-formatted text, not screenshots

Answer (score 0):

As the second screenshot shows, you need to install pandas for your the python interpreter that you use, like this:

```
C:\Users\Uros\untitled\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install -U pandas
```

Comment: When I do that I get this in the end : Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Uros\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mlktexl1\pandas\

Comment: It might be because of an outdated version of setuptools, you could try upgrading them using the same command in the answer: "C:\Users\Uros\untitled\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install -U pip setuptools"

Comment: I get this exception :https://prnt.sc/q55w2y

*I just installed Python recently on my new laptop but on my older one Pandas works. Maybe I did something wrong when I installed it?

Comment: From the original screenshots in your question, it looks like there are multiple installations of Python on your laptop. You could remove all of them and only install one clean version to work with.

Comment: I fixed it, problem was I didn't create new python project, i just opened the one sent from my other laptop :3. Thanks anyway :D